# Django: How to update multiple rows in admin table?

Tags: python, django

I got the next problem: I want tu update the "TOTAL PAGADO" field with the previous column "PRECIO TOTAL" by selecting multiple rows and then apply an action called "Saldar precio" which return the "SALDO" field to 0.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWMNM.png)

and the return is that:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oghc1.png)

i've been trying something like that:

```
**models.py**
class PedidoCliente(Pedido):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Pedidos (Ingresos)"
        verbose_name_plural = "Pedido (Ingresos)"

    def get_precio_total(self):
            detalle_pedido = DetallePedidoCliente.objects.filter(pedido=self)
            precio_total = 0
            for detalle in detalle_pedido:
               precio_total += detalle.precio_venta
            return "%.2f" % (precio_total, )

     precio_total = property(get_precio_total)

class DetallePedidoCliente(DetallePedido):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Detalle pedido"
        verbose_name_plural = "Detalle pedido"

    precio_venta = models.DecimalField(max_digits=16, decimal_places=2, default = 0)
```

```
**admin.py**
class PedidoClienteAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
      list_display = (... ,'precio_total',...)
      actions = [...,'saldar_precio',...] 

      def saldar_precio(self, request, queryset):
          t_p = queryset.update(total_pagado= queryset[0].get_precio_total())
      return t_p
```

where .get_precio_total() is a calculated column, not a field.

I know that the problem here is that 0, that only return the first selected value, but i dont know how to solve it.

It's my first time doing a question here so sorry if i'm breaking some posts rules (and sorry for my english)

Thanks!

**SOLUTION**
The problem here was that calculated column wasn´t a field, so i transform it to a field. How?

```
**models.py**
class PedidoCliente(Pedido):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Pedidos (Ingresos)"
        verbose_name_plural = "Pedido (Ingresos)"
    
    precio_final_nuevo = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2,verbose_name="Precio $")

    @property
    def get_precio_total(self):
            detalle_pedido = DetallePedidoCliente.objects.filter(pedido=self)
            precio_total = 0
            for detalle in detalle_pedido:
               precio_total += detalle.precio_venta
            return "%.2f" % (precio_total, )

     def save(self, *args, **kwargs):    
        self.precio_final_nuevo = self.get_precio_total_nuevo
        super(PedidoCliente, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

So, now i can call 'precio_final_nuevo' as a field, which stores the calculated column 'precio_total'.

Comment: You may use stack overflow in portugues if you are more confortable -> https://pt.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 0):

<s>You can use the [F expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) to address this issue. It will allow you to get another column on the same row</s>

```py
from django.db.models import F

total_qs_updated = queryset.update(total_pagado=F('precio_total'))
```

update:    
calculate the 'precio_total' in db

```py
from django.db.models import IntegerField, Case, When, Value

total_qs_updated = queryset.update(total_pagado=Case(
    When(
        detallepedidocliente__isnull=False,
        then=Sum('detallepedidocliente__precio_venta')
    ), default=Value(0)))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. 'precio_total' is not a field, is a calculated column. If I apply that line, i got a field error: `Cannot resolve keyword 'precio_total' into field. Choices are:...`

Comment: updated my answer, what I do is calculate the sum in database and update total_pagado with it! try it and keep me posted if it worked or not =)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but it doesn´t run. I'll put what i made for resolve this. Thanks again MSR974!